# Background job Framework Needed in Production

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-batch, batch-processing

We have a requirement, where we have to run many async background processes which accesses DBs, Kafka queues, etc. As of now, we are using Spring Batch with Tomcat (exploded WAR) for the same. However, we are facing certain issues which I'm unable to solve using Spring Batch. I was thinking of other frameworks to use, but couldn't find any that solves all my problems.

It would be great to know if there exists a framework which solves the following problems:

> 1. Since Spring Batch runs inside one Tomcat container (1 java process), any small update in any job/step will result in restarting the Tomcat server. This results in hard-stopping of all running jobs, resulting in incomplete/stale data.

WHAT I WANT: Bundle all the jars and run each job as a separate process. The framework should store the PID and should be able to manage (stop/force-kill) the job on demand. This way, when we want to update a JAR, the existing process won't be hindered (however, we should be able to stop the existing process from UI), and no other job (running or not) will also be touched.

I have looked at hot-update of JARs in Tomcat, but I'm skeptical whether to use such a mechanism in production.

Sub-question: Will OSGI integrate with Spring Batch? If so, is it possible to run each job as a separate container with all JARs embedded in it?

> 2. Spring batch doesn't have a master-slave architecture.

WHAT I WANT: There should be a master, where the list of jobs are specified. There should be slave machines (workers), which are specified to master in a configuration file. There should exist a scheduler in the master, which when needed to start a job, should assign a slave a job (possibly load-balanced, but not necessary) and the slave should update the DB. The master should be able to send and receive data from the slaves (start/stop/kill any job, give me update of running jobs, etc.) so that it can be displayed on a UI.

This way, in case I have a high load, I should be able to just add machines into the cluster and modify the master configuration file and the load should get balanced right away.

> 3. Spring batch doesn't have an in-built alerting mechanism in case of job stall/failure.

WHAT I WANT: I should be able to set up alerts for jobs in case of failure. If necessary, a job should have a timeout where it should able to notify the user (via email probably) or should force stop the job when the job crosses a specified threshold.

Comment: Did you have a look at [vertx](http://vertx.io/) ? When I used it it was not production ready, but maybe now it is

Comment: Did you look at  [quartz scheduler](https://quartz-scheduler.org/) framework ?

Comment: @stalet Yeah I did take a look at it. It provides synchronization between different schedulers trying to run a job. However, it says clearly in the docs "NOT" to run it on different machines. - http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [vertx](http://vertx.io/) can do the trick.

> Since Spring Batch runs inside one Tomcat container (1 java process), any small update in any job/step will result in restarting the Tomcat server. This results in hard-stopping of all running jobs, resulting in incomplete/stale data.

Vertx allows you to build microservices. Each vertx instance is able to communicate with other instances. If you stop one, the others can still work (if there are not dependant, eg if you stop master, slaves will fail)

```
Vert.x is not an application server. 
There's no monolithic Vert.x instance into which you deploy applications. 
You just run your apps wherever you want to.
```

> Spring batch doesn't have a master-slave architecture

Since vertx is *even driven*, you can easily create a master slave architecture. For example handle the http request in an vertx instance and dispatch them between severals other instances depending on the nature of the request.

> Spring batch doesn't have an in-built alerting mechanism in case of job stall/failure.

In vertx, you can set a timeout for each message and handle failure.

```
Sending with timeouts
When sending a message with a reply handler you can specify a timeout in the DeliveryOptions.
If a reply is not received within that time, the reply handler will be called with a failure.
The default timeout is 30 seconds.

Send Failures
Message sends can fail for other reasons, including:
There are no handlers available to send the message to
The recipient has explicitly failed the message using fail
In all cases the reply handler will be called with the specific failure.
```

**EDIT** There are other frameworks to do microservices in java. [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/) is one of them, but I can't talk much more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Let me take a look and get back.

Comment: I need a UI for this. Is it possible to integrate this with Spring Batch?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring, but there are an official example [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples) and some articles like [this one](http://perfectworldprogramming.com/embed-vert-x-eventbus-into-your-spring-application-with-ease/)